# Download only the text from a webpage content in Python

Tags: python, http, urllib2

How can I download **only** text/html/javascript from of a webpage in Python?

I'm trying to get some statistics about the text written by authors of blogs. Needing only the text, I want to increase my program speed by avoiding the download of images, etc.

I'm able to separate the text from the HTML markup language. So my intention is mainly avoiding downloading aditional content in a webpage (like  images, .swf or the like)

So far I use:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3'
        headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=60)
content_type = response.info().getheader('Content-Type')
if 'text/html' in content_type:
   return response.read()
```

But I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing (i.e. downloading text only)

Comment: I would recommend looking at the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for much easier handling of HTTP requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python BeautifulSoup one of the best for parsing webpages

```
import bs4
import urllib.request

webpage=str(urllib.request.urlopen(link).read())
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage)

print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: I want to do this for performance reasons (I  will update my question.).  Therefore, I don´t know if your answer suits me.  However it was useful so +1